# Power rule for derivative operator $D^n$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, noncommutative-algebra

I was playing with commuting the derivative operator $D$ and the scalar multiplication of $x$ applying to a function $f$. If $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denote de commutator, then:

$$[D,x]f=D(xf)-xDf=f+xDf-xDf=f$$

If we abstract for applying to a function, $[D,x]=1$. I notice that when you choose an arbitrary $n$-grade of $D$, denoted as $D^n$, the commutation with $x$ gives a "power rule", similar to the derivation of just $x^n$, the last exponent meaning the usual $n$-power of $x$:

$$[D^n,x]=nD^{n-1}$$

For example:

$$[D^2,x]f=D^2(xf)-xD^2f=D(f+xDf)-xD^2f$$
$$=Df+xD^2f+Df-xD^2f=2Df $$

$$\Rightarrow [D^2,x]=2D $$
If we go further and generalize to $[D^n,x^m]\dots$

$$[D^n,x^m]=\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}D^k(x^m)D^{n-k} $$

which resemble to the binomial formula.

Is there a meaning for this result?

Comment: How do you get $[D,x]f=f$?

Comment: @Karl $[D,x]f=D(xf)-xDf=f+xDf-xDf=f$

Comment: I think the sum should start at $k = 1$ in your case, but really it's just [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) applied to $f$ and $g(x) = x^m$. You have one less term but that's because in the commutator you get rid of $x^m D^n f$. As for a "meaning" for the formula, I'd say a good way to think about this is to see that the binomial theorem is true on rings as long as the concerned elements commute, and as such it's true for the ring of smooth functions with addition being regular addition and the product being the differentiation.

Comment: Do tell me if what I've said would be good enough for you as an answer, I'll leave it as a comment for now.

Comment: @BrunoB you was right. In my notebook was with $k=1$. The less of your reply, I'd study it. Thanks. I'd also wanted to ask about a "transpose" $D$, but not in the common use in functional analysis, instead as a left operator acting on function, because you can rewrite the formula as $(D^t+D)^n$ acting on the left on $x^n$, but I only guessing here.

Comment: @BrunoB For the rest of your reply*

Comment: Uh, I retract what I said about "the ring of smooth functions", Leibniz's rule can't be the binomial theorem for a ring due to three operations being used (addition, multiplication, differentiation) and differentation not being distributive with addition nor multiplication (because again, you need all three operations). My apologies, I must've been tired.

Comment: @BrunoB no problem. I know zero abstract algebra, so you motive me to study it.

Comment: I think the ring multiplication here is composition of operators, and some of the operators themselves are multiplication by a scalar. So you have to be careful with notation to avoid confusing them.

Comment: @Karl I know very little about ring theory, but yes. Multiplication in this sense is composition of operator and it form a noncommutative algebra. One can think of $x\cdot:C^1\to C^1$ I think.

Comment: Meaning? It is basically McCoy's [1932](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.18.11.674) standard combinatoric identity...